# How do I read a username from the firebase realtime database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the structure of my database, where the long string of characters is the user id.

How do I read the username of the user if I know the user id is set to the variable uid?

[image: Database Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty basic firebase operation and if you haven't already, you should read their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/).

But, if you have the user ID stored in a variable named `uid`, eg:

```
const uid = "14hxjh...";
```

Then you can read that data by doing (assuming users is a top level node):

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${uid}/username`).once("value").then(snap => {
    const username = snap.val();
    // Do things with username.
})
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! The documentation was a bit confusing to me because I'm still a novice haha.